# How to prove that a matrix multiplied by vectors have a solution iff every $b \in \mathbb{R^2}$ Ax=b has a solution

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove:

Let A a 2-by-2 Matrix and the two equations:

$$(1) Ax = \begin{pmatrix}2 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} $$

$$(2) Ax = \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$$

There is the following statement:

Both these equations have a solution iff for every b$\in$$\mathbb{R^2}$ the equation Ax=b has a solution.

Proving one side is easy because you can claim that for every b$\in$$\mathbb{R^2}$ Ax=b has a solution, so for these specific vectors there's a solution for sure.

I'm having trouble proving the other way.

Comment: Could you give more details on the question you are asking? Such as what you tried to do to solve it and where it comes from?

Comment: @Milloupe I've elaborated more on the specific exercise

Comment: Ok, it's much better with the specific vectors, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to see it is to decompose any vector $b$ into the base given by your two vectors $b_1 = ( 2,0 )$ and $b_2 = ( 0, 2 )$.

Concretely, let $b=\begin{pmatrix}c_1 \\ c_2\end{pmatrix}$ the vector for which you want to find $x: Ax=b$. You can notice that:

$$
b = c_1 \frac{b_1}{2} + c_2 \frac{b_2}{2}
$$

Then, if you have found $x_1 : Ax_1 = b_1$ and $x_2:Ax_2=b_2$, then you have:

$$
Ac_1 \frac{x_1}{2} + Ac_2 \frac{x_2}{2} = c_1 \frac{Ax_1}{2} + c_2 \frac{Ax_2}{2} = c_1 \frac{b_1}{2} + c_2 \frac{b_2}{2} = b
$$

This works because you have two vectors ($b_1$ and $b_2$) that *span* $\mathbb{R_2}$.